# IPv6 routing with multiple interfaces

Tags: linux, ipv6

I have a linux server with two NICs and IPSec (Libreswan) installed.

I have two networks that should get routed through VPN, but it works only one of the networks.

So far I could debug that for the working network `ip -6 route get <ip on net 1>` and `ip -6 route get <ip on net 2>` returns the correct device / source ip so that the policy shown on `ip xfrm policy` gets applied.

If I add a default route that uses the correct interface it does not work either, the `route get` still determines the wrong NIC/IP.

Adding routes to use the correct device works, but that means i have to add the networks to ipsec configuration and routing, which is error-prone.

Is there an alternative / proper way?

I am using Ubuntu 23.10, network configuration is done via systemd-networkd, but NICs use DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

While looking around I found `RouteMetric` (of `[DHCP]` section), which was set to 100 for both interfaces.

after setting the preferred one to a lower value (90), the routing works correctly now!

```
[Match]
Name=ens6 # interface with correct source IP for VPN policy

# ...

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=90
# ...
```

```
[Match]
Name=ens7

# ...

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=100
# ...
```